# Tricky calculus problem. Could involve differentiating under the integral and/or FTC

Tags: integration, derivatives

I came across this question in a math gre prep book:

> Evaluate the derivative of 
>   $\displaystyle\int_0^x \frac{\cos(xt)}{t}dt$.

In the first step of their solution, they do the following without explaination:

$$f'(x) = \frac{\cos(x^2)}{x} -\int_0^x\frac{t\sin(xt)}{t}dt$$

To me, this looks like an application of the FTC, together with another step that I do not understand.  I've tried to play with the problem and get it to fit with the multivariable chain rule, as well as looked in Rudin for rules for differentiating under the integral.  Does anybody here have some insight?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See Leibniz's rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign . Note that you have $x$ both in the integrand and in the limit of integration.

Comment: Let $F(x)$ denote this function. Try breaking up $F(x + \Delta x) - F(x)$ into two parts, one looking like $\int_x^{x + \Delta} \ldots$, and the other like $\int_0^x \frac{\cos(x + \Delta)t - \cos(xt)}{t} dt$. In other words, break up the variability into two parts, one where the limits of integration are being varied, the other where the integrand is being varied -- it's similar to how you prove the product rule.

Comment: How can you differentiate a function that is not even defined? $\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}$ has a non-integrable singularity in a right neighbourhood of the origin ($t\to 0^+$).

Comment: To make sense, $\cos(xt)$ has to be replaced by $1-\cos(xt)$ or something like that.